# Serialize to JSON string tracemalloc in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, tracemalloc

I have to serialize to JSON string the result of `tracemalloc`.

```
current_mem, peak_mem = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
overhead = tracemalloc.get_tracemalloc_memory()
stats = tracemalloc.take_snapshot().statistics('traceback')[:top]

summary = "traced memory: %d KiB  peak: %d KiB  overhead: %d KiB" % (
    int(current_mem // 1024), int(peak_mem // 1024), int(overhead // 1024)
)

logging.info("%s", summary)

out_lines = [ summary ]
for trace in stats:
    out_lines.append("---")
    out_lines.append( "%d KiB in %d blocks" % (int(trace.size // 1024), int(trace.count)) )

    logging.info("%s", out_lines)

    out_lines.extend( trace.traceback.format() )

out_lines.append('')

data = {}
data['traceback'] = '\n'.join(out_lines).encode('utf-8')

res = json.dumps(data)

print(res)
```

When I dump data to JSON I get a

```
Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

From logging I can see the string output:

```
2020-01-08 11:54:25 - INFO - traced memory: 35 KiB  peak: 91 KiB  overhead: 31 KiB
2020-01-08 11:54:25 - INFO - ['traced memory: 35 KiB  peak: 91 KiB  overhead: 31 KiB', '---', '1 KiB in 4 blocks']
```

and then in the loop:

```
2020-01-08 11:54:26 - ERROR - ['traced memory: 35 KiB  peak: 91 KiB  overhead: 31 KiB', '---', '1 KiB in 4 blocks', '  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/routing.py", line 256', '    self.delegate.finish()', '  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2195', '    self.execute()', '  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2228', '    **self.path_kwargs)', '  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326', '    yielded = next(result)', '  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1590', '    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)', '  File "/tornado/handlers/memTraceHandler.py", line 56', '    self.write(json.dumps(response.getData()))', '---', '0 KiB in 2 blocks']
```

So which is the `b""` string I cannot serialize?

Comment: There is no code that dumps anything to JSON, so your question lacks a [mcve].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt modified please consider to remove your close request. This does not make any help to the SF community! You should ask first to add more info and then if anything happens close. In my opinion this way helps users to improve their questions and help SF definitively.

Comment: I'd happily vote to reopen your question. However, concerning my vote to close, ATM it still stands. You are a regular here and should have known that your question was bad. Further, it still is bad. If you had extracted a [mcve], you could have easily found the error yourself. Also, searching for the error message could have given you a bunch of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YOU** are creating the `bytes` object here:

`data['traceback'] = '\n'.join(out_lines).encode('utf-8')`

That's what calling `encode` does.

Simply do:

`data['traceback'] = '\n'.join(out_lines)`

And it will dump out fine.